# How to compare two Hashtables with multiple duplicate values in both

Tags: java, list, hashtable

```java
Hashtable<Integer,String> List1= new Hashtable<>();
List1.put(1,"A");
List1.put(2,"A");
List1.put(3,"B");
List1.put(4,"C");

Hashtable<Integer,String> List2= new Hashtable<>();
List2.put(1,"C");
List2.put(2,"C");
List2.put(3,"A");
List2.put(4,"B");
```

I have these two tables how can I compare them and show in percentage how equal they are?
Assuming these are two Hash tables.
Ex: `List1` and `List2` have 90% of the same values.

Comment: `Map` cannot contain duplicate keys (i.e. keys that are equal to each other) and your sample says `List1<V,K>` which is ... nothing that makes sense. Can you provide some *actual code* of what your input looks like? Also you need a much more precise definition what you mean by "how equal"? How equal are [A=1] and [A=2]? 50%? 0%?

Comment: They have different keys but same values in the same map.

Comment: I have two hashtables that contains word as a value and number as its key. There are duplicate values in both tables but they have different keys. I want to compare how equal the two hashtables are. Right now iam trying to compare the two tables with the values not the keys. Since they are duplicate values in both the percentage it wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong input, I have corrected it now! @Joachim Sauer

Comment: @BadBoysTrue: fair enough, but we still don't know what metric you want to use for "equality"? What are the desired outputs for `{1=A}`/`{1=B}`, `{1=A}`/`{2=A}` and `{1=A, 2=B}`/`{1=A}`?

Comment: I really don't know how to think here actually. I have so far iterated through the first table and taken a value from it and searched for it in the second table and returned the number of times that values appears in the second table. Since that value appears several time in the first table and in the second my percentage calculation shows wrong %.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you don't know how to implement it, but you **also** don't exactly know what "it" is! We can't help you implement "it" unless we understand what you mean by "it". So as a first step, find out what you **actually want to happen** (i.e. find out what the desired outputs for the inputs I gave you are) and then try to implement *that*. You're implementing stuff before you even know what the output should be. That is doomed to fail.

Comment: @BadBoysTrue check out my answer - it's probably something similar what you are looking for. It may need correction but you didn't specify full requirements so I had to make some assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure whether I understood you correctly but something like this probably solve your issue:

```java
public double calculateOverlapPercentage(Hashtable<Integer, String> list1, Hashtable<Integer, String> list2) {
    if (list1 == null || list2 == null || list1.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    long overlapCount = list1.entrySet().stream().filter(l1 -> list2.containsValue(l1.getValue())).count();
    return (double) overlapCount / list1.size();
}
```